# Number of occurrences of next value in a vector in R

Tags: r, sequence, sequential-number

I have a vector with random numbers from 1-7 and I want to be able to determine the next number in the vector that follows the first value so that I can look for patterns and get a 7x7 matrix of values that shows how often a specific number follows another.

First number in rows and count of next number in columns.

I am trying to do this with a double loop currently, but am getting confused in the process.

For example-

```
Example vector-

floor(runif(10,1,8))
[1] 3 5 6 6 6 1 7 7 5 3

Answer-

  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1 0  0  0  0  0  0  1
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 0  0  0  0  1  0  0
4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
5 0  0  1  0  0  1  0
6 1  0  0  0  0  3  0
7 0  0  0  0  1  0  1
```

Comment: `table( v[1:(length(v)-1)], v[2:length(v)] )` ? - where `v <- c(3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 1, 7, 7, 5, 3) `

Comment: That did it and was way easier than I was making it! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a vector

```
v <- c(3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 1, 7, 7, 5, 3)
```

if you call `table()` on the vector you get a count of each element

```
table( v )
# v
# 1 3 5 6 7 
# 1 2 2 3 2
```

If you call `table()` on mulitple vectors, you get a count for each combination of values.

Since you want to 'count' the number of times a value appears with the value next to it, you can call `table()` on the original vector, and the same vector shifted one-value to the right.

```
table( v[1:(length(v)-1)], v[2:length(v)] )

#  y
# x  1 3 5 6 7
#  1 0 0 0 0 1
#  3 0 0 1 0 0
#  5 0 1 0 1 0
#  6 1 0 0 2 0
#  7 0 0 1 0 1
```

Which can be made more succinct (courtesy of [Julius Vainora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320535/julius-vainora) ) by

```
table(head(v, -1), tail(v, -1))
```

Note: the result doesn't include the `NA` rows you've got in your question.

Comment: Also `table(head(v, -1), tail(v, -1))`.

Comment: If you want the full table of all integers, use `v2 <- factor(v, min(v):max(v))`. You will get 0's not NA's though.